# Converting string array to byte array and back

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to convert a string array to byte array. I would like to use `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` but it only accepts `String` and `Char()`. This is the code

```
Dim aStringArray(2) As String

aStringArray(0) = "FileName"
aStringArray(1) = "FileSize"

Dim stringArrayBytes() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(aStringArray) `this is wrong
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to combine the array into a single byte array try this

```
    Dim aStringArray(1) As String

    aStringArray(0) = "FileName"
    aStringArray(1) = "FileSize"

    Dim stringArrayBytes As New List(Of Byte)
    For Each s As String In aStringArray
        stringArrayBytes.AddRange(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s))
    Next

    Dim bytarray() As Byte = stringArrayBytes.ToArray
```

Comment: I think `.ToList()` is redundant there

Answer (score 1):

Here little bid different approach, based on your example :)

```
Dim aStringArray(2) As String

aStringArray(0) = "FileName"
aStringArray(1) = "FileSize"

Dim allStrngItems As String = String.Join(String.Empty, aStringArray)
Dim allBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(allStrngItems)
```